# Changing image in ListView (with Simple Adapter)

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm following tutorial from [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql) link to create a listview containing data from database. It consists of a picture (by default - switched off light bulb) and two texts - name (room) and status (on/off) of the database record. At the end of AsyncTask which loads data from database I want to scan through the list and change the picture for every position where status equals "1" to switched on light bulb.

But the image doesn't change. As if the listview wasn't refreshing.

Every help would be appreciated.

```
public class LightingActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray status = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> statusList;

private static String address_getall = "http://192.168.2.112/db_lighting_getall.php";
private static String address_update = "http://192.168.2.112/db_lighting_change.php";

private static final String SID_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String SID_ARRAY = "Lighting";
private static final String SID_ID = "light_id";
private static final String SID_NAME = "name";
private static final String SID_STATUS = "value";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.lighting_activity);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    statusList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new LoadData().execute();

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // ...Listener...
        }
    });
}

class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LightingActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(address_getall, "GET", params);

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(SID_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                status = json.getJSONArray(SID_ARRAY);
                for (int i = 0; i < status.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject data = status.getJSONObject(i);
                    String light_id = data.getString(SID_ID);
                    String light_name = data.getString(SID_NAME);
                    String light_status = data.getString(SID_STATUS);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(SID_ID, light_id);
                    map.put(SID_NAME, light_name);
                    map.put(SID_STATUS, light_status);

                    statusList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // Error
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        LightingActivity.this, statusList,
                        R.layout.lighting_list, new String[]{SID_ID, SID_STATUS, SID_NAME},
                        new int[]{R.id.light_id, R.id.light_status, R.id.light_name});
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                // I tried doing it like this:
                ListView lv = getListView();
                for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
                View v = lv.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
                TextView light_status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.light_status);
                String status = light_status.getText().toString();
                if (status.equals("1")) {
                // Everything works till here - I checked with Toasts
                    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.light_icon);
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_on);
                    lv.invalidateViews();
                    lv.refreshDrawableState();
                }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please be tolerant, I'm new to java :)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong in your code that it's beyond saving! I suggest you google about how to load data to a ListView using AsyncTask. There are many examples. With a quick search this looks close to your needs.

http://android-er.blogspot.gr/2010/07/load-listview-in-background-asynctask.html

just a few pointers

```
1) onPostExecute, onProgressUpdate and onPreExceute of AsyncTask are executed 
   in the UI thread so the runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {}) is not necessary.
   Only the doInBackground method is executed in another thread;

2) Put all the logic about what each rows shows like inside the getView method 
   of the adapter.

3) To update the views of a listView you change the data in the ArrayList and then 
   call  notifyDataSetChanged() on the ListView 's adapter. This causes all of the views 
   to be re-drawn. And because all the logic is in the getView method your views 
   are showing what the data contains.
```